# Import spring boot application in eclipse using gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to run this project from https://github.com/fmohr/PROSECO
It is my first time working with Spring and Gradle
I added gradle buildship (version 6.5), Spring boot IDE, when I try to import as gradle project in eclipse I got this error:

org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.

I tried to change the gradle version in gradle-wrapper file to 6.5 and import again, the import is ok but when starting the server I got errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul2IE.png)

What is the proper way to run this project please
Thank you

Comment: "when starting the server I got errors" - what are the errors?

Comment: it is supposed to create some sub-files in commons directory, but eclipse didn't show them and there is yellow icon on the folder.

Comment: you should first try to build outsite your idea, by executing command line `./gradlew build` from the project root directory. do you get same errors as in IDE? please post these errors, this can help to understand your issue.

Comment: I noticed also that there is some files that I can see with file explorer but they are not viewable in eclipse

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I tried both from IDE and with cmd. The error is that they point to a directory which is not found. The unfound directory is supposed to be created. I wil update my post with a screenshot of the error

Comment: What is your Java version ? When I checked the project it is using gradle 4.x and you are  using gradle version 6.5. If you are using Java version 11 there can be an issue with the gradle version of the project

Comment: Update: I edited `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and updated the gradle version to `6.5` and then build the project using `./gradlew build`. Project built without any issues. I am using Java version 11

Comment: @kaushik I tried your suggestion yes the project build. But when I run the application with bootRun the execution stoped in 91% did you get the same issue?. thank you

Comment: @Yasminette, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
` This is the error I am getting and that's a programmatic exception.

Comment: @kaushik this is not the same error I get, instead he did not find a the file domains in webserver. thank you